# Over fitting dfittool. Need explanation

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am using 'dfittool' in Matlab to fit my data with 'non-parametric distribution' option, as in:

[image]

Could anyone please explain, why the pdf (density function) fit to my data is exceeds '1'? And with varying width of the bin, I could get the fit less then '1'. Why is this happening? Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063026/normalizing-a-histogram-and-having-the-y-axis-in-percentages-in-matlab

I have followed the three methods mentioned above but the Y-values are not less than '1' as it should be.|
One more thing: Can we show the data in bar chart in place of histogram?

Comment: Please don't tag this kind of question with "pdf". The "pdf" tag refers to a file format from Adobe, not to a density function in Matlab. Thanks!

Comment: It's perfectly fine for a pdf to exceed one. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105455/80812) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok). This seems to really be about math/stats rather than programming and thus off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are misled by the idea that you're fitting a *probability* density function; you are fitting apparently something else.

If what you displayed as bars is a histogram of the data values counted in some bins, please norm it to the number of points, so the total sum of the rectangle areas will be indeed 1 and not the number of points in your data. Then your fitting will follow the normalization.

**Later edit:** just noticed the `dfittool` bit in you posting... are you sure that you don't have some scale annotations in you're graph that you're not paying attention to? something like **×10<sup>-3</sup>** or similar?