# Dice simulation with matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new on this forum. First of all, I find it very interesting to have such a website were everyone can get help in different domains. Thank you very much.

So I have a problem: I was supposed to resolve the following problem:

- Simulate with `rand` `ntrials` of rolling a dice.
- if `rand()` in `[0, 1/6]` then 1 was thrown;
- if `rand()` in `(1/6, 2/6]` then 2 was thrown
- ...
- if `rand()` in `(5/6, 1]` then 6 was thrown.
- Generate with hist an histogramm of the results of ntrials.

This is what I did:

```
ntrials = 100;
X = abs(rand(1,ntrials)*6) + 1;
hist(floo(X))
```

Now there is a second exercise that I must do:

- two dice are thrown and S is the sum of the 2 dice
- Compute the probability that S respectively accept one of the value 2,3,4,5.....12.
- Write a Matlab function `twoTimesDice` that the theoritical result through a simulation of the throw of 2 dice like in the first exercise.

That is what I tryed:

```
function twoTimesDice
  x1 = abs(rand(1,11))*6 + 1;
  s1 = floor(x1);      % probably result of the first dice
  x2 = abs(rand(1,11))*6 +1;
  s2 = floor(x2)       % probably result of de second dice
  S = s1 +s2;
  hist(S);
end
```

Can you tell me please if I did it well?

Comment: In the first function you can remove `abs`. Also, use `hist(floor(X),1:6)` to plot the histogram for those values only. You may also use `X = randi(6, ntrials); hist(X, 1:6)`. Similar comments apply to the second function

Comment: Just as a hint: you could also use `randi(6,n)`. Your construction is not intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I would use floor instead of abs,

```
X = floor(rand(1, ntrials)*6) + 1;
```

as it returns the values you are looking for, or as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2732801/daniel) commented, use

```
randi(6)
```

which returns an integer.

Then you can just run

```
hist(X,6)
```

For the second part, I believe they are asking for two dice rolls, each being 1-6, and not one 2-12.

```
x = floor(rand(1)*6) + 1;
```

The distribution will look different. Roll those twice, add the result, that is your twoTimesDice function.
Roll that ntrials times, then do a histogram of that (as you already do).

I am not sure how random rand() really is though.

Comment: Instead of `rand` / `floor` I recommend `randi`

Comment: right, that is random integer, right? Let me add that.

Comment: Please indent code lines or use tags `\`\`` for inline code, not quotation blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a dice roll between 1 and 6 can be done by `randi()`.

So first, use `randi()` instead of `floor()` and `abs()`:

```
X = randi(6,1,ntrials)
```

which will give you an array of length `ntrials` with random integers ranging from 1 to 6. (you need the 1 there or it will return a square matrix of size ntrials by ntrials). [randi documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)

In the function my personal preference would be to request the number of trials as input.

Your function then becomes:

```
function twoTimesDice(ntrials)
  s1 = randi(6,1,ntrials);      % result of the first dice
  s2 = randi(6,1,ntrials);      % result of the second dice
  S = s1 +s2;
  hist(S);
end
```

For a normalised histogram, you can replace `hist(S)` by:

```
numOfBins = 11;
[histFreq, histXout] = hist(S, numOfBins);
figure;
bar(histXout, histFreq/sum(histFreq)*100);
xlabel('Value');ylabel('Percentage');
```

(As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063026/normalizing-a-histogram-and-having-the-y-axis-in-percentages-in-matlab))

Comment: Oh my god!! You are so great in  this forum:) 20 years ago it was unimaginable to find so quickly help. Your contributions was soooo useful. Thank you very much!!!  Best wishes Y. Patrick