# How to turn y axis of histogram to show percentage ranging from 0 to 1

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

I want to change the y axis of the histogram to show percentages ranging from 0 to 1. this is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    myTolerance=1e-12; % in erg units.
      nbins=50;
    for j=1:ntM/100:ntM

       H = histfit(Wkinet(abs(Wkinet(:,j))>myTolerance, j) * erg2eV, nbins);
    %Select from column j all rows in column j whose absolute values are 
    %greater than the tolerance.
    H(1).delete; %%Remove bins, only keep the fit.
       set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
        set(gca, 'XScale', 'log'); % Make logarithmic X
         yt = get(gca, 'YTick');
        set(gca, 'YTick', yt, 'YTickLabel', 
        yt/numel(Wkinet(abs(Wkinet(:,j))>myTolerance)))

      pause;
   end
```

## This is what is currently looks like:

[image: Output Graph]

## This is what I want:

[image: Desired output graph]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output you are getting?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to normalize a histogram in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5320677/8239061)

Comment: Also related: [Normalizing a histogram and having the y-axis in percentages in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21063026/8239061)

Comment: im sorry i cant make it work in mine @Secret

Comment: No problem.  Can you make a Minimal, Complete, Reproducible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I'm not understanding what you're getting versus just what you want.  Did the related links have what you needed?

Comment: ive added a picture to the initial question..i want the y axis to range from 0 to 1

Comment: make it look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTLgY.png lets say

Comment: Setting `YTickLabel` is always a last resort (unless you want to put names at each tick instead of a number). Instead of changing `YTickLabel`, change the values you plot. For example `H = H/max(H)` or `H = H/H(1)`, depending on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you ,but i cant understand how i should write it to fit my problem @Cris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to simplify the discussion below, the line

```matlab
H = histfit(Wkinet(abs(Wkinet(:,j))>myTolerance, j) * erg2eV, nbins);
```

is equivalent to

```matlab
data = Wkinet(abs(Wkinet(:,j))>myTolerance, j) * erg2eV;
H = histfit(data, nbins);
```

This means below we'll assume `data` is a vector.

---

`histfit` computes and plots a histogram though [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html), then fits a function to it through [`fitdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html). Since you don't want to plot the histogram itself, just stick to `fitdist`:

```matlab
pd = fitdist(data,'Normal'); % this is the default distribution used in `histfit`, is it correct?
x = linspace(min(data),max(data),200); % 200 points in the graph, you might want to change this?
y = pdf(pd,x);
plot(x,y);
```

Now it's simple to normalize the plot however we want. For example set the first element to 1:

```matlab
pd = fitdist(data,'Normal');
x = linspace(min(data),max(data),200);
y = pdf(pd,x);
y = y/y(1);    % <<< Normalize
plot(x,y);
```

Comment: But what i meant is on the y axis to show the percentage  ranging from 0 to 1 .would it be right if i instead of y=y/y(1) had y =y/sum(length(data)) ?? @Cris

Comment: @nikos: `fitdist` already returns a normalized distribution (integral is 1). So if you want that, don’t change its output at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set limits on your y-axis using

`ylim([1e-3 1]) %lower limit is nonzero since it's plotted on log scale`

or

`set(gca, 'ylim', [1e-3 1])`

Comment: Thank you ,but it doesnt seem to be working as i want it